# Connecting to SMTP server failing on Linux but not Windows

Tags: python, ssl, smtp

In a python script, I have the following:

```py
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(sender_server, 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, sender_password)
    server.sendmail(
        sender_email, email, message.as_string()
    )
```

On the Windows machine I wrote the script on, everything works as expected and the email is sent and delivered without issue. However, when I try to run the same code on my Linux VPS, a TimeoutError is thrown every time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 151, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(sender_server, 465, context=context) as server:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1037, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

What could be causing this difference? My Google searches didn't bear much fruit, but maybe I'm just searching for the wrong terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

This means that access to the remote system is likely blocked somewhere on the way to the system. Given that you have this problem on a "Linux VPS" it is likely that the connection is blocked by the company hosting this VPS or that you need to configure your machine specifically to allow such access. Check with your specific hoster and its documentation.